# DB Design/Structure problems

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, wcf, api

Hi i'm having difficulty figuring out a structure to my db and am looking for some suggestions im how i should structure it.

So my problem so far is this.... 
I have one application that has data relating to Users and i also have access to a WCF Service and what i need is to grab my Users ID's and then assign them data from my WCF Service and store this data in its own db.

So a single User can have access to many Services for example

userID = UID1

serviceCode = PPV, KFM, LFL, LFH etc...

But i need to have a new application in MVC C# that will allow me to grab Users from my Web API and Services from WCF and be able to add services to existing Users.

Can anyone help me structure my db?? im not entirely sure what would be the best layout for my problem, i have tried a few examples but i get a lot of repetitive data which im trying to avoid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a relational database user, you should build one table for each type of data. 
For example:

```
User
```

{
id int,
name varchar(50)
etc,..}

```
services
```

{
id int,
type varchar(10),
etc...}

Then you could just get them together with a relational table that has one identity column and both ids. By doing this you will be doing a N to N relationship in the DB. Easy to select/list and insert by code.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, this is very similar to what I had originally started with. Yes this helps alot I can see how this would work in my situation. The one thing I was worried about the most repetitive data entries but having them seperated would avoid it wouldnt it I think.

Comment: Hi, the thing here is that you can give more possibilities for each relation with more tables. That depends on your program logic. Anyways, one table must have lots of rows to join the categories, the categories and users will have less, thats how you minimize the data storage.